# Running ssh-agent through puppet

Tags: git, ssh, cron, puppet

I am using Puppet and I want to pull Git repos through cronjobs with a specific user. I have a private key located in my ~/.ssh directory, which I add to my ssh-agent with this exec:

```
  exec {
  'add-ssh-key':
    cwd => '/home/user/.ssh',
    command => "bash -c 'eval $(ssh-agent) ssh-add rsa_key'",
    path => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin',
    provider => 'shell'
  }
```

According to the provision the agent was started and the identity added to the agent. However I can't pull the repo (neither can the cronjob) because I'm probably not connected to the correct ssh-agent (when pulling it asks for a password).

Is there a another way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a section to the user's `~/.ssh/config` file to instruct it to use the key when connecting to the `git` server.

```
Host my-git-server
    Hostname git.example.net
    User gituser
    IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/rsa_key
```

Have Puppet make sure that the private key has appropriately limited permissions.

There is no need to involve `ssh-agent`.

Comment: I have already done that. I created an identical config file in .ssh/ and I set the private key permission to 600. But when I try to pull the repo it keeps asking for a password and the only solution I found to circumvent this is adding the key to the ssh-agent.

Comment: Ok, for some reason it only works when I name my key "id_rsa". But since you used "rsa_key" in your example I presume that this should work with any given name?

Comment: Since `id_rsa` is the default key that `ssh` will use, I suppose your config is not even being used. I took the `rsa_key` file name from your question, assuming that was the file name. - Just deploying the private key to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is indeed the most simple and safe approach.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but why doesn't it work with another filename? I might need to use multiple keys in the future and I can't name them all id_rsa. [This](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) instruction also uses another filename.

Comment: Use `ssh -vv` to get to the bottom of what configuration is used and why what does not work.

Comment: Okay, for some reason it works now.. I don't know. Thanks for the help.